# FPS Drop in Cocos2djs

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I aim to create this pattern of game play with one main Lobby Scene and other GameScene opening through window.open.

But even when i try this with empty hello world project to open multiple window, I get restricted due to high drop in FPS.

So basically I need to know is this setup possible in cocos creator , that can even four windows render simultaneously without FPS taking a hit.
Any guidelines if any can be provided to help achieve this will be appreciated.

The game in reference pic i think is made via angular ,maybe thats why it is so smooth even after ten windows.

My team posted issue on cocos2djs but no help :- https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/help-regarding-multi-window-game-in-cocos-creator/42688

Comment: Why do you need so multi-window game? I believe that in any app when you open many windows the CPU is working a lot harder. But if you must use the multi-window open feature in your app my try multi-tabs instead.

Comment: I am developing a card game where player can be play on a multiple table at a same time, if I will give multiple tab they cant be play and see a table action on run time. Any help how I can be achieve it?

Comment: what is the minimum fps and for how long it stays at a minimum? also how many drop calls do you have?

Comment: Draw call is 243 & FPS is coming 15, if opening 4 windows.

Comment: And if you open only one window, what is the FPS and draw calls?

Comment: Draw call 243, FPS 60

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of dig-in and according to your answer in the comment, I think you can try a different approach "split-screen game". I believe when a new window opened it use the same assets and it drops the FPS.

I don't know what is the best practice for "split-screen game", but I have one suggestion on how to implement it:

1. Create a prefab template of the main screen.
2. Create different layers (node) for each screen
3. Add the prefab to the layer, for example :

   ```
   layer with 1 screen - 1 prefab

   layer with 2 screen - 2 prefabs (duplicate prefab)

   etc.
   ```
4. If you move between screens (layers) don't forget to make active false to the last node and destroy all his children.

Also, I think your drop calls it a little bit high for even one window app, Try maybe to check it also.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: thank you for sharing a suggestion. If you dont mind can you create a demo project for me, we can pay you for that effort.